# How to keep the map order in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I define a map in my code like:

```
(def templates {:list1 {:create_time "create_time"
                        :recharge_amount "recharge"
                        :invest_amount "invest"
                        ;; something else
                        }
                :list2 {:create_time "ct"
                         ;; something else
                        }
                ;;something else 
                })
```

I want the map keep the order by what I am defined. 
How to solve it?

Comment: Use a sorted map (see `sorted-map`).

Comment: @DiegoBash `sorted-map` won't maintain insertion order (unless you insert the keys in sorted order, of course).

Comment: You could keep a parallel vector of keys, as inserted. Here, `(def template-log [:list1 :list2])`.

Comment: You can interop with Java and use a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your data won't change, you can use `array-map`:

```
(def templates
  (array-map
    :list1 {}
    :list2 {}
    :list3 {}))

(seq templates)
;; => ([:list1 {}] [:list2 {}] [:list3 {}])

(keys templates)
;; => (:list1 :list2 :list3)
```

Why the constraint with constant data, you ask? Well, an array-map might turn into a hash-map after basically any modification operation (if its contents grow too big to offer efficient lookups).

Alternatively, if you're open to external dependencies you could see if [amalloy/ordered](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered) fits your needs.

Comment: Indeed it seems like, these days at least, that small-ish, defined-from-constants map constructions _are_ array-maps out of the box. i.e. `(type {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})` yields `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`

But if they can magically turn into hash-maps at the whim of the system, that might give one pause about relying on them staying array-maps if they're ever used to create new maps.